# For SEO, should I append the site's main keyword to the title tag of every page?

Tags: seo, title

I'm using Joomla as CMS. It allows appending the website name before or after the actual site name. So I do it after the site name.

If I put the main keyword in the website name, it will be appended to every page title after the site name.

Is it better to remove the appending of the same phrase (website name/product name and so on) to every page?

I'm afraid the main keyword which if indexed quite good will lose ranking if I use it only in a few pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website title shouldn't contain the same set of keywords on every page.

Appending the business name at the end is OK.

Try to create a unique title for every page based on what the page is all about. In some pages, you may have covered more keywords in that case you may not have space to append the business name at the end so you don't need to.

Do not append set of keywords at the end in every page meta title.

Comment: It could also confuse any branding attempts that a search engine may make.

Comment: Hey thanks. Its not a set of keywords but rather something like "ACME Rental Software", were "Rental Software" is a keyword.

Comment: It's kind of business name so you could you in more pages. But i would say better be it home page only and in inner pages, if the search will be based on keywords + brand, Google will amend in any way. Meaning as explained have meta based on the page content. In some pages, if you may struggle to have full length then have business name like in contact us, about us pages etc.